# How do I connect to a CRM IFD web service?

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have taken the code from the SDK and made just one modification to set the authentication type but when I try to connect I get an "Unauthorized" error.

My code is:

```
// Set up the CRM Service.
CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
token.AuthenticationType = 2;
token.OrganizationName = "TESTCRM";


CrmService service = new CrmService();
service.Url = "https://testcrm.ifdtestsystem.com/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx";
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
//service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Bill", "Password");


// Create an account entity and assign data to some attributes.
account newAccount = new account();
newAccount.name = "Greg Bike Store";
newAccount.accountnumber = "123456";
newAccount.address1_postalcode = "98052";
newAccount.address1_city = "Redmond";


// Call the Create method to create an account.
Guid accountId = service.Create(newAccount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using SPLA (IFD) you need to also populate the token with a crmticket.The ticket can be retrieved by quering the CrmDiscoveryService.

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151010.aspx) contains a reasonable sample how to use CrmDiscoveryService to obtain a ticket and set up CrmService.

Note that Credentials property for the service will no longer be required as all authentication information will be inside the ticket.

Hope this helps