# How to retrive records from OData service of crm 2011 IFD

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I have the fallowing code.

```
var ctx = new XrmContext(new Uri(serviceUrl));
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
ctx.AccountSet.First();
```

Silverlight version is (In fiddler we have here the same result)

```
var ctx = new AdzzContext(new Uri(serviceUri));

ctx.HttpStack = System.Data.Services.Client.HttpStack.ClientHttp;
ctx.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "admin");

var query = ctx.AccountSet;

var async = new DataServiceCollection<Account>();
async.LoadCompleted += async_LoadCompleted;
async.LoadAsync(query);
```

What give me the falling error.

> The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make
>   sure that the top level element is a valid Atom element or belongs to
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' namespace.

When I look at fiddler I see a redirect to the adfs server
[image: Redirect]

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759500/how-do-i-connect-to-a-crm-ifd-web-service), but it is for CRM 4, And in the context of the OData I can't put a token.

My target is so,

To make a Silverlight library for business logic (BL) purpose - So I can debug it easily in my computer - and it will run perfectly in the CRM environment,

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to generate the early bound classes (using crmsvcutil.exe) and specify the `ServiceContextName` parameter.

Assuming your context is `XrmContext`, you need to instantiate in this way:

```cs
var context = new XrmContext(service);
```

where `service` is the `IOrganizationService` web service.

You don't need to specify the credentials because the connection credentials are handled when you instantiate the `OrganizationServiceProxy`

Sample code: http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/sample-code-for-using-iorganizationservice-in-crm-2011/

Comment: This is good for Silverlight plugin - but for running on a Silverlight at the local computer - it will not work if I'm not in the domain of the CRM (I edited the question)